# Reading input and moving files with similar names

Tags: powershell, file-move

I am trying to create a script which reads the first line of a file and then moves all of files with a similar naming convention up a level.

These are 3 example files:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\location\PYYYYYYYYY.txt.asc
C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea\PYYYYYYYYY.tt.asc
C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea\PYYYYYYYYY.t.asc
```

The script I have so far is:

```psh
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "Location Filename"
$locationfilename = Select-String C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea\*.txt.asc –pattern $location  -Context 1
$locationfilenames = $locationfilename.basename
$locationarea = "C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea"
$locationlocation = "C:\Users\USERNAME\location"

Select-String C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea\*.txt.asc -Pattern $location -Context 1 |
  Out-File -Append C:\Users\USERNAME\location\logs.txt
Move-Item -Path "$locationfilenames" -Destination "$locationlocation"
```

Comment: plus 1 for `$locationlocation`

Comment: What issue are you having with your script?

Comment: it brings back the following error,

Move-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '> C' does not exist.

At line:10 char:10
+ Move-Item <<<<  -path "$paymasterfilenames" -Destination "$paymasterlocation"
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (> C:String) [Move-Item], DriveNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is arising here:

```
$locationfilename = Select-String C:\Users\USERNAME\location\holdingarea\*.txt.asc –pattern $location  -Context 1
```

Assuming you're just trying to get the filename, this should work:

```
$lcoationfilename = $location | Split-Path -Leaf
```

If it's the parent folder you're after, then this is appropriate:

```
$lcoationfilename = $location | Split-Path -Parent
```

If for some reason you're on a version of PS that doesn't have Split-Path, let me know and I'll edit to a more appropriate solution.